# How do I update the timezone to Eastern time in mysql properly?

Tags: mysql, time

I am trying to set the timezone on my mysql server
In my my.cnf file I have:

```
default-time-zone = '-05:00'
```

When I run `SELECT NOW( )` in mysql I get `2015-02-05 04:13:57`
Note: It should have returned '2015-02-05 10:13:15'

I want to set it so it has the Eastern time zone.

I ran the query: `SELECT @ @global.time_zone , @ @session.time_zone`

```
@@global.time_zone  @@session.time_zone
SYSTEM              SYSTEM
```

Comment: What is the Timezone in your mysql-client interface?

Answer (score 4):

This should help you:

**in the file "my.cnf" in the [mysqld] section**

```
default_time_zone='+00:00'
```

**TO SEE WHAT CURRENT TIME ZONE IS SET TO:**

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone;
```

**@@session.time_zone variable**

```
SELECT @@session.time_zone;
```

**TO SET THE TIME ZONE:**

```
SET time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
SET @@session.time_zone = "+00:00";
```

Comment: I put SET time_zone = 'America/New_York'; and it is giving me an error #1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'America/New_York'

Comment: You can try this as well. SET time_zone = "-5:00"  <--- to whatever difference your time zone is.  I have put 3 different options to change the time zone.  The the other one and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NOW( )
```

function from **mysql** get your system time check your system time zone

Comment: I just got SERVER as a result